# Is the 'x' in ConstPtr& x in callback functions specific to message types?

Tags: ros, msg-subscriber, ros-kinetic, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm new to ROS and I'm an amateur when it comes to pointers. I just did the subscriber and publisher tutorials and I am currently experimenting and converting them into classes for future use. I noticed that in the callback function it has the following parameters:

```
 void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
```

then I opened another cpp code with a subscriber and found:

```
  void joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy);
```

My question, is 'joy' and 'msg' specifc to use for their message::message type? How can I know what to put after the ConstPtr& say for sensor_msgs::Range? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302137/is-the-%27x%27-in-constptr&-x-in-callback-functions-specific-to-message-types?/) by [J. J.](https://answers.ros.org/users/37271/j.-j./) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2018-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; the variable name is not specific to the message type or the callback. You can name the argument `joy` or `msg` or `gerorge` or whatever you want.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [J. J.](https://answers.ros.org/users/37271/j.-j./) on 2018-08-31**:
Thank you. That cleared up my mind.